# what does each of these options mean?

Tags: java

```
java -Djava.library.path=../lib 
     -classpath ../lib/wrappertest.jar:../lib/wrapper.jar:Service.jar:../lib/mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar 
     -Dwrapper.key=Ksxtsmvr7iAmVJ-T 
     -Dwrapper.port=32001 
     -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 
     -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=1731 
     -Dwrapper.version=3.3.0 
     -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper 
     -Dwrapper.service=TRUE 
     -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 
     -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 
           org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp com.jobirn.Service
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-classpath` tells the VM how to find classes

`-Dx=y` sets the system property `x` to value `y`; the exact effect depends on the property:

- `java.library.path` is used to find native libraries
- The rest (`wrapper.*`) looks like it's read by a third party library.

Comment: Is -Dx=y global or just change the system property inside the application?

Comment: Just for that single session - it's global inside the VM, but only for that process.

Answer (score 5):

`-classpath` sets the class path for the JVM, i.e. the path where it will look for classes. The others (starting with `-D` ) all set [System properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()). Of these, `java.library.path` sets the path where the JVM will look for native libraries. The other system properties are used to configure the [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/props-jvm.html) product.

Answer (score 1):

-classpath is a : separated list of directories or jar files for Java to look for classes

Each -D is an property that is being set.
java.library.path is the standard location for Java to look for its libraries, such as rt.jar
`wrapper.x` are most likely properties for `org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp`
These can also be set in Java using `System.setProperty("property.name", "value");`

`org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp` is the actual java class being run.
`com.jobirn.Service` is the first argument to the above class and will show up as `args[0]`, assuming the standard `public static void main(String[] args)`